# How to install Lubuntu and remove everything from the computer?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu

I have an USB drive with Lubuntu. I would like to remove everything from a computer that has an old installation of Ubuntu and replace everything by this new Lubuntu installation (I do not want to create a new partition). I have already installed lubuntu in my computer, but I realized that it created a partition with Lubuntu instead of removing the old installation and partition. Furthermore, I have not been able even to access the new Lubuntu installation from the usual boot. I am not sure what I have been doing wrong. When I usually install the usual Ubuntu, it asks if I want to remove everything or to create a new partition. How can I do that?  I have been used ubuntu for many years, but I consider myself a beginner. Now I want to remove the old Ubuntu installation and to remove also the new partition with Lubuntu, and to create the only partition with a Lubuntu.

Comment: Are you saying if you choose the option to 'erase and install', it is just adding a new partition?  Can also use the "try L/Ubuntu option and erase/format everything first with gparted then install.

Comment: Yes, that was the option that I chose, but it did not erase everything. Should it?

Comment: Try looking at the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html   You haven't specified your release of Lubuntu (there are 3 different installers available for supported releases of Lubuntu, but they vary on release, the manual link I've provided is for modern Lubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: I don't really understand your situation, however if you've mounted any partition in the *live* session before you start the installer (`calamares` for modern Lubuntu; but you didn't provide release details), some options will not show such as "*Erase disk and install*" because you can't erase the mounted partition(s) until after you've unmounted them.  Mounted partitions can include *swap* if you have one, so use *KDE Partition Manager* (assuming 20.04) to ensure no partitions are mounted before running `calamares` or *Install Lubuntu*

Comment: The version I am trying is LUBUNTU 18.04.

Comment: Which installer/ISO are you using?   Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is available with two different installers chosen by the ISO you download.   (`ubiquity` which is the same as standard Ubuntu desktop, or *debian installer* which is what older releases of Ubuntu Server used; the alternate choice for low-ram (<768MB ram) machines)

Comment: I downloaded from here: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/

Comment: Maybe I did not choose to unmount. I installed many times the Ubuntu, but I believe it never asked it to me.

Comment: For starters, lubuntu.net is neither a Lubuntu, nor Ubuntu web site. If unsure where to get a Ubuntu *flavor* from, go to ubuntu.com (not a search engine unless you can pick legitimate sites), eg. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will send you to https://lubuntu.me/ which is the Lubuntu web site.  I don't believe that's your issue though. Did you verify your ISO? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 which works for *flavors* too), then validate your write to thumb-drive? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)